# Canvas.drawRoundRect is only creating roundrect on bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I'm trying to convert my ImageView into a RoundedRectangle. I have this code:

```
bitmap = holder.profile_image.getDrawingCache();
Bitmap MutableBitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
holder.profile_image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(MutableBitmap);

Paint paint = new Paint();

RectF rectF = new RectF(0,0,90,100);

paint.setAntiAlias(true);

canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF,5,5,paint);

//This sets the ImageView
holder.profile_image.setImageBitmap(MutableBitmap);
```

The issue is that it only seems to DRAW a Rounded Rectangle on top of my Image instead of converting my image into a Rounded Rectangle. How can i fix it so that it converts my bitmap into a Rounded Rectangle shape?

Comment: Have you tried this link before https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/3292810/3746306

Comment: @NileshDeokar I've used the Stack Overflow link before. It just replaces my image with a black rectangle.